# SvelteKit WebApp to PWA (Progressive Web App), How to do it in the most simple way possible?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, vite, sveltekit

**Introduction**:

I am developing a webapp using the [`SvelteKit`](https://kit.svelte.dev/) framework,

I implemented some basic functionality for making accessible even to mobile devices:

- I made it responsive
- implemented light/dark themes
- refactored the code

So basically I think I have a ready-to-use website

that can easily be usable on mobile devices.

---

**What I want?**:

I want that my website to be downloaded as a apk

to make it working also Offline

and hopefully even be publishable on Google Play Store.

---

**My research**:

I did some research before asking,

and I found that we can use a concept called [`PWA`](https://web.dev/explore/progressive-web-apps?hl=it), a acronym for Progressive Web App.

---

**What is the problem?**

It's seems easy, but in reality,

It turn out to be very difficult to implement using framework like 'SvelteKit'

---

**Question?**:

Is there any simpler way than these before,

to transform a vite sveltekit webapp to a PWA?

> I want also to be simple because I want to
>
> focus more on Business/App logic than implementing PWA logic.

---

**What things, the answer should solve?**

- No need to recreate the app from scratch, using native technologies
- No need to complex the code using new components, beside the DOM original ones (NO [Condova](https://cordova.apache.org/)/[Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) Approach)
- One source code for Android and IOS
- Offline / Caching Ability
- Download Ability
- easy to implement on new, and even on more old/complex projects.
- it should work with SvelteKit/ViteJS (even with TypeScript and Libraries such as TailwindCSS)
- No need to disactivate SSR.
- The configuration should be done one time, or the least times possible.

---

**What I tried, if interest you but these are failed tryies** *(you can skip this part)*:

> - First and obvious way, code it by yourself from scratch everytime 
> but 'SvelteKit' has a lot of scenarios that you need to consider since it leverage 'SSR'. 
> But as you know is time consuming 
> to focus on making PWA functionality to work 
> than using that time to make the app even more better or solving some bugs. 
>  - use a PWA library called [Workbox](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/workbox?hl=it) create by Google itself, 
> here their github https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox 
> and even with this library this process is still difficult, especially using SvelteKit framework. 
>  - using a PWA library, based on top of Workbox, called [Vite PWA](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/). 
> The landing page of this library use as marketing phrase "*Zero-config and framework-agnostic PWA Plugin for Vite*". 
> Theoretically, it should be true, At the start seems to do his job, 
> but in my experience it contains some bugs that you definitely doesn't want to deal with... 
> for example one of them is this: https://github.com/vite-pwa/vite-plugin-pwa/issues/40 
> It creates bugs that don't make sense, basically making your app over-complex for nothing. 
>  - and much more...

> all of these are failed examples,
>
> I hope you will find a better way than these

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is the most easiest way to make a PWA from SvelteKit, that should work always, without any library:

1. create a folder called `service-worker`

> you can't use another name, it's important to use specifically this

---

2. put this new folder inside your `/src` folder

> DON'T insert it inside '/lib' or '/routes', but inside their parent '/src'

---

3. inside the new folder `/service-worker`, create a new file called `index.ts`

   (or `index.js` if you don't like using Typescript)

> below you can see a image, I created for you, to make you understand visually the structure (semplified version):
> [image]

---

4. copy and paste this code in the file you created in step n. 3:

```js
/// <reference types="@sveltejs/kit" />

// @ts-nocheck
import { build, files, version } from '$service-worker';

// Create a unique cache name for this deployment
const CACHE = `cache-${version}`;

const ASSETS = [
    ...build, // the app itself
    ...files  // everything in `static`
];

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    // Create a new cache and add all files to it
    async function addFilesToCache() {
        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE);
        await cache.addAll(ASSETS);
    }

    event.waitUntil(addFilesToCache());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    // Remove previous cached data from disk
    async function deleteOldCaches() {
        for (const key of await caches.keys()) {
            if (key !== CACHE) await caches.delete(key);
        }
    }

    event.waitUntil(deleteOldCaches());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    // ignore POST requests etc
    if (event.request.method !== 'GET') return;

    async function respond() {
        const url = new URL(event.request.url);
        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE);

        // `build`/`files` can always be served from the cache
        if (ASSETS.includes(url.pathname)) {
            return cache.match(url.pathname);
        }

        // for everything else, try the network first, but
        // fall back to the cache if we're offline
        try {
            const response = await fetch(event.request);

            if (response.status === 200) {
                cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
            }

            return response;
        } catch {
            return cache.match(event.request);
        }
    }

    event.respondWith(respond());
});
```

> like I said you don't have to understand these lines of code, just copy and paste and they should work in most of cases (it's written by SvelteKit mainteiners by their-self)
>
> for more details about this code...
>
> I got this code here: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/service-workers#inside-the-service-worker
>
> ---
>
> all the files inserted in this folder are threated by default as service-workers...
>
> *is cool, right?*
>
> service workers aren't used only for PWA,
>
> but also for much more...
>
> for example for making your app work even in background,
>
> but thats is definitely another topic.

---

5. create your `manifest.json` file, inside your `static` folder (you can't use another folder unfortunately)

   this part can't be automatized,

   but is easy to get it...

   the most important data that you need to add for the most basic app are:

- `icons` (with at least one image)
- `name`
- maybe also `"display": "standalone"` to make the webapp feels like a android app by eliminating the browser bar.

  here the most simple json markup that you can use as starting point:

```json
{
  "name": "APP NAME",
  "description": "YOUR DESCRIPTION",
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icons/myIcon512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    }
  ]
}
```

> if you want a more detailed `manifest.json` see this docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest

---

6. add this line in your `app.html`

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

---

7. Congratulations!, you made your first sveltekit webapp to be a PWA!

- refresh your windows to see that a new install button appears
- and in your mobile phone your app works even when opened without internet (in the second opening of your app)

---

as you see this way is easy/fast/efficient,

and it takes less than one minute!

and the most important thing: no need for external libraries

have a nice coding day!

Comment: Why don't you take the `prerended` page to put them in the cache like below?

```js
import { build, files, prerendered, version } from '$service-worker';

const ASSETS = [
 ...build, // the app itself
 ...files, // everything in `static`
 ...prerendered // prerendered pages
];
```

Comment: That is a very nice suggestion, thanks. however, to simplify it, I don't want to change the available code here because I got this code here: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/service-workers#inside-the-service-worker . thanks! @Big_Boulard

Comment: apple devices want a link rel for pwa in the html file. just store the image in your static folder and use this in your main html file
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%sveltekit.assets%/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" />